Flutter keyboard is flickering going throw next fields on OTP widget
i have a weird behavior on my application i have built a custom OTP screen and when i test it the keyboard shows a weird behavior the system keyboard flicker when moving throw fields i have tried different solutions but nothing worked for me:
Note: i don't want to use external packages.

screen code:
build(BuildContext context) {
// AppBar height
final double appBarHeight = kToolbarHeight; // Default appBar height is 56.0
final double statusBarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;

return Scaffold(
  extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    elevation: 0.0,
  ),
  body: Container(
    width: double.infinity,
    height: double.infinity,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: ThemeController().themeGradient,
    ),
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: appBarHeight + statusBarHeight,
        left: 16.0,
        right: 16.0,
        bottom: 16.0,
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(
            'التحقق من الجوال',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 24.0,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            'تم إرسال رمز التحقق إلى رقم جوالك الرجاء تحقق من الرسائل',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white70,
              fontSize: 16.0,
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 32.0),
          Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                // Pinput(
                //   length: 6,
                // ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    OTPFieldWidget(
                      controller: textEditingControllerOne,
                      first: true,
                    ),
                    OTPFieldWidget(
                      controller: textEditingControllerTwo,
                    ),
                    OTPFieldWidget(
                      controller: textEditingControllerThree,
                    ),
                    OTPFieldWidget(
                      controller: textEditingControllerFour,
                    ),
                    OTPFieldWidget(
                      controller: textEditingControllerFive,
                    ),
                    OTPFieldWidget(
                      controller: textEditingControllerSix,
                      last: true,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 48.0),
          CustomElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => Get.offAllNamed(HomepageScreen.routeName),
            label: 'تحقق',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

}
OTP widget code:
TextField(
  controller: controller,
  onTap: () {
    controller.selection =
        TextSelection.collapsed(offset: controller.text.length);
  },
  onChanged: (value) {
    if (value.isNotEmpty && !last) {
      FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
    }
    if (value.isEmpty && !first) FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
  },
  autofocus: autoFocus,
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  maxLength: 1,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    fontSize: 24.0,
  ),
  cursorHeight: 32.0,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
      vertical: 8.0,
    ),
    counterText: '',
    constraints: BoxConstraints(
      maxWidth: 48.0,
    ),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.white,
        width: 2.0,
      ),
    ),
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        width: 2,
        color: Colors.white70,
      ),
    ),
    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        width: 2,
        color: Colors.white70,
      ),
    ),
    errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        width: 2,
        color: Colors.white70,
      ),
    ),
    focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        width: 2,
        color: Colors.white70,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

Thanks for your time, happy coding for you all.

what are solutions you tried?
are you tried to define multiple focusNode for each field?
are you tried to make the autoFouuc = true for the first field only?
maybe keyboard type of numbers make some issues are you tried using numberWithOptions ?
please clarify the steps you did for tying to solve this issue

Hello saayeed, i have tried define focusNode and pass it for the fields (did not work), make sure all fields keyboard type of number (did not work), and the autoFocus (did not work), ill try numberWithOptoins and check if it will works, thank you for your comment.
